# success msg from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have success and error image, I need to show the success message from my jQuery, like,

[image]

I need to show like this in a label control, I've created a css class named "success", if I can call this class from my jQuery I can display this image, is it possible, can anyone help me.

If I use alert like `"alert("Changes saved successfully.");"`, I can get the alert box, but what I need to do is in a label control I need to show this success image as well as `"Changes saved successfully."` text.

I tried like `lblMessageBox.html("addClass","success" + "Changes saved successfully.")`, its not working

Comment: can u please add some code for better understanding ?

Comment: Hiya man, I reckon soon you will be asked a very valid question by other guys: i.e. What have you tried :) do you have any code to show us, have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: @gdoron lol :) ha ha :P may I say - Buzinga! have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: @Tats_innit. Why all of your posts and comments end with _" have a nice one, cheers!"_ ?

Comment: I just updated my question, just check it

Comment: @gdoron i think he "cheers" lot :) lol ;)

Comment: Y this much of downvotes for this question, is it possible or not?

Comment: @Shanish it's because everyone wants to help you, not do it for you. You need to show us what you've tried. Have you even looked at the docs for jQuery or Googled for solutions?

Comment: sorry I dunno how to proceed it, I think I can show the status message like lblMessageBox.html("Changes saved successfully"), if I want to show the text alone, but I need to show the image as well, thats what I dunno how to proceed

Comment: I tried like lblMessageBox.html("addClass","success" + "Changes saved successfully."), its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Shanish, you're clearly struggling so here's something to get you started.

Let's assume you have a `message` container something like this:

```
<div id="message">
    <img src="" /><span></span>
</div>
```

The container doesn't need to be a div. It could equally be a p, span, td or th.

Some css directives in your style sheet will provide background-color, font-size, padding, margins etc.

Now, to set any image/message, you would do something like this :

```
function setMessage(imgSrc, text, duration) {
    imgSrc = String(imgSrc) || '';
    text = String(text) || '';
    duration = Number(duration) || 0;
    var $message = $("#message");
    var fn = (imgSrc === '') ? 'hide' : 'show';
    $message.fadeIn('fast').find("span").text(text).end().find('img').attr('src', imgSrc)[fn]();
    if(duration && !isNaN(duration)) {
        setTimeout( function(){$("#message").fadeOut('fast')}, duration );
    }
}
```

And you would call the function like this :

```
setMessage('green_tick.png', 'Changes saved successfully', 3000);
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v4mca/) - adapt as necessary to get exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks for ur response Beetroot-Beetroot, I'll try

Comment: I found the solution thanks alot Beetroot